# Easy and fast load datagrid from textfile with 100k rows using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, vb.net-2010

I have a created a program with VB.net, where text file is used to load datagrid, but its very slow, there is a lot of code, when there are many line imports from text file.

Is there any simpler way to code this, so datagrid loading isn't so slow?

```
Private Sub Load_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Load.Click

OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*"
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select Text File for Path"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "Select File"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ok Then
        txttblnm.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        txtfilenm.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(txttblnm.Text)
        txtfilenm.Text = txtfilenm.Text.Substring(0, txtfilenm.Text.Length - 4)
        Label7.Text = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(txttblnm.Text)
    End If

    If Len(txtfilenm.Text) = 8 And CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        Dim textfiles() = Directory.GetFiles(Label7.Text, "*.txt")
        For Each file As String In textfiles
            Call dgv1_load()
            Call Access_export()
            Call clear_item()
        Next
    ElseIf Len(txtfilenm.Text) >= 9 Then
        MsgBox("Please Load DATA", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Load Data Error")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you format your code examples a little?

Answer (score 0):

You're interacting far too much with the user interface. Every interaction with the gridview + textboxes is expensive.

What you should do is start by creating a DataTable and fill this with the row data.

Then after it's all loaded set the datagridview.DataSource to this table and everything will be drawn only once.

```
    Private Function ParseFile(filename As String) As DataTable
        Dim result As New DataTable()
        result.Columns.Add("colname 1 ....")
        result.Columns.Add("colname 2 ....")

        Using inputFile As New StreamReader(filename) 'Open text file

            Do Until inputFile.EndOfStream
                Dim row = result.Rows.Add()
                row(0) = "blah"
            Loop
        End Using
        return result
    End Function

    Private Sub ShowResult()
        dgv1.DataSource = ParseFile(filename)
    End Sub
```

Comment: your type of code is right but my specific data load to data table is very difficult to me for writing code, if you able to modify my code then i easily solved my problem. thanks in advance +1

Comment: Not a code writing service .... we're just here to give advice. I'd suggest you start writing the parsing code again from scratch. Name every variable you use with a meaningful name, add comments and some notes about the file structure. Then once you've made a start come back to stackoverflow and ask for some more help